# Dreamweaver dialogue windows are huge

Tags: windows-8.1, dreamweaver

Good Afternoon, im having a bit of a problem with dreamweaver :/

When opening a dialogue box within dreamweaver CS6, for example the dreamweaver preferences windows, or CSS editor window, it appears very large, almost twice the size of my screen.

For example: Screenshot:

[image]
I have checked my systems DPI Settings and they are set to 100%.

Im running windows 8.1. My screen resolution is 1366 x 768

Ive tried changing screen resolutions and different DPI sizes.

Any ideas would be appreciated greatly?

Comment: ANSWER: I managed to fix this issue by deleting all of my fonts and replacing them with a fresh download from here: http://www.withsteps.com/2621/windows-8-default-font-download-repair-kit.html

Comment: Welcome to SU.  You're allowed (and encouraged) to answer your own questions.  So once the system allows you, please post you comment as an actual "Answer". :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by deleting all of my fonts and replacing them with a fresh download from here:
http://www.withsteps.com/2621/windows-8-default-font-download-repair-kit.html